# ProxyPass to node.js server with Apache vhost on ARVIXE with cPanel

Tags: linux, node.js, apache, cpanel, proxypass

I am trying to host some node.js servers on an Arvixe VPS host with cPanel and Apache installed. Apache is integrated into cPanel, and is running such that it's listening on port 80 for a whole bunch of stuff at a number of IP addresses and host names.

I have two node.js servers that are running on the localhost on different ports, and I need to set up Apache to proxy requests on a specific host name at port 80 to my two node.js servers. Now, I am not a well-versed linux guy, I've been Microsoft stack for years, however I'm trying to branch out and get into the JavaScript stack with Angular, Node, and MongoDB (woot! Single language full stack! Love it!)

I did some research, determined that configuring httpd.conf has to be done carefully with cPanel, due to the way it's web UI can rebuild the config. I added a vhost.local file to /var/cpanel/templates/apache2/, and added the following:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName my.hostname.com

    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:8181
    ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://localhost:8181

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8282
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8282
</VirtualHost>
```

I ran the following two commands:

```
  /usr/local/cpanel/bin/apache_conf_distiller --update
  /usr/local/cpanel/bin/build_apache_conf
```

And received the message:

> Built /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf OK

The above new vhost was added to my `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf` file (twice, for some reason...not sure why). When I run `/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -S`, I get the following:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
1.2.3.4:80          is a NameVirtualHost
      default server 1.2.3.4 (.../httpd.conf:123)
      port 80 namevhost 1.2.3.4 (.../httpd.conf:123)
      port 80 namevhost my.hostname.com (.../httpd.conf:123)
      port 80 namevhost my.hostname.com (.../httpd.conf:123)
      port 80 namevhost abc.arvixevps.com (.../httpd.conf:123)
1.2.3.4:443         abc.arvixevps.com (.../httpd.conf:abc)
127.0.0.1:80        is a NameVirtualHost
      default server abc.arvixevps.com (.../httpd.conf:abc)
      port 80 namevhost abc.arvixevps.com (.../httpd.conf:abc)
127.0.0.1:443       abc.arvixevps.com (.../httpd.conf:abc)
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:*                 is a NameVirtualHost
      default server abc.arvixevps.com (.../httpd.conf:abc)
      port * namevhost abc.arvixecps.com (.../httpd.conf:abc)
Syntax OK
```

The PROBLEM, however, is that when I go to my.hostname.com, instead of getting content served up by my express or restify servers, I get redirected to a canned cPanel page at: http://my.hostname.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi. Something, somewhere, in the rest of the virtual hosts configuration seems to to be overriding my configuration, and the proxy forwarding. I do not know enough about Apache, however, to figure out why, so some expert advice would be welcome.

Comment: Well, everyone can nevermind this. Something is apparently stuck somewhere along the pipeline from me to my server. It works if I go through the anonymouse.org proxy...it just doesn't work for me. So, the config above is, apparently, 100% valid and working as it should be.